# On the transgression in the Serre spectral sequence

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

This is probably very well known, something obvious to expect, and written somewhere. But, I do not recall any reference.

Let $F\to X\stackrel{p}{\to} B$ be a fibration where $F$ and $B$ are $(f-1)$-connected and $(b-1)$-connected, respectively. Then, we have Serre exact sequence
$$H_{b+f-1}F\to H_{b+f-1}X\to H_{b+f-1}B\stackrel{\tau}{\to}H_{b+f-2}F\to\cdots$$
where $\tau$ is the transgression in the Serre spectral sequence for the above fibration. On the other hand, there is a $(b+f-2)$-equivalence $\Sigma F\to C_p$. So, writing the homology exact sequence of the cofibre sequence yields 
$$\cdots\to H_jX\to H_j B\to H_jC_p\to\cdots$$
which in the above range, $j<b+f-2$, yields the first exact sequence. Now, can weidentify $\tau$ with the zigzag
$$H_jB\to H_jC_p\leftarrow H_j\Sigma F\stackrel{\simeq}{\leftarrow}H_{j-1}F.$$
I would be very grateful for any reference.

Comment: Transgression, homology suspension and its relation to the Serre s.s. is very well explained in McCleary's "A User's Guide to Spectral Sequences". However, you might have to fill the details by yourself.

Comment: Probably check Jeff Strom's book.

Comment: See also the lecture notes by Paul Shick.  These include details.